# Has the US government said anything about forcing Apple to have multiple app stores on their devices?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, technology, regulation

The UK has passed/will pass a law forcing Apple to give users the option to switch between multiple app stores (for example, the Microsoft and Samsung app stores), but only in the UK so far. Has the U.S. government said anything about maybe following up on this? Have there been any whispers about it?

EDIT: It'd be great if an answer (that says Apple has to give users the option) identifies what OS' (if not all are required to) would be given the switching-app-stores feature.

Comment: Not only the UK but also the European Union: https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2024/01/apple-announces-changes-to-ios-safari-and-the-app-store-in-the-european-union/

Comment: Leaving this as a comment for the moment as an answer on this front could be rather longer, but based on the [Epic Games V. Apple lawsuit[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_Games_v._Apple) which is likely related to answers here, would you consider answers that consider it from a court ruling, or a state-level legislative branches, or is this focused primarily on the federal government's legislative or executive branches?

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st As long as it clearly answers whether or not Apple has to give users the option to switch app stores, I'll accept it as an answer (may not hit the accept *button* if a better one comes up or someone gives counter-evidence, or another reason).